# Initial current in an RL circuit

Tags: inductor

I would like to confirm that I am going about this exercise the right way.

"After a long time of being open the switch closes at t=0. Find $_L(s) and i_L(t)." (See picture below)

[image]

Do I need to take any initial conditions into account? There are none given, but as stated, the circuit has been on for a long time. Can the initial current be written as simply V_s/2R?

What I did was sum the voltages together V_S(t) = i_L*R + L*di/dt, then I took the Laplace transform and got I(s) = V(s)/L*1/(s + R) and from that I got i_L(t) = V_s(t)/L*e^(-Rt)

Comment: yes, initial current can be written as V_S/2R,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should consider that the initial current is V/2R, as inductors behave as short circuits in the steady state.

However, without doing any calculations, there are many things that tell me your answer is incorrect:

1. The dimension for your current is Voltage/Inductance,
   which is wrong, should be voltage/resistance.
2. The dimension of your exponent is R*t, which should be dimensionless, and it is
   not.
3. When t goes to infinity, according to your answer, the current goes to zero. By the same 
   logic that allowed you to determine that the initial current before the switch is flipped is V/2R, what should be the current after a long time has passed after the switch is closed?

HINT: Your voltage V is constant. What is the Laplace transform of a constant? You have V(s). Also, what is the Laplace transform of a derivative \$\large \frac{df}{dt}\$ ? Are you sure it's just \$s\cdot F(s)\$?

Answer (score 0):

The statement "after a long time" is essentially a code meaning that the system is at Steady State, meaning that all the derivatives with respect to time will be equal to zero (i.e., nothing is changing).  That should be enough to give you your answer.

Of course, you should always take a hard look to make sure that this makes sense for your problem.

Comment: So at t=0- the current is V_S/2R and the derivative is zero? Thanks :)

Comment: You got it!  All Steady State assumptions can be dealt with in that way

Comment: One thing that is puzzling me is this: The voltage over the entire circuit is V_s. Would the current through the resistor not be (V_s - V_L)/2R? Or 2V_R/2R, where V_R is the voltage drop over the resistor. Or is there no voltage drop over an inductor in steady state?

Comment: You can assume an inductor is a short in steady state, and a capacitor is open.